# Setting 0 when NO rows from select statement with multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have this table
(Simplified, my query have more tables involved)

ConsignmentItem

```
ID |Item code| Name | Quantity
 1 |  00000  |  A   |    3
 2 |  11111  |  B   |    2
```

And this other table

PickingItem

```
ID |ConsignmentID|Quantity
 1 |      1      |    1
```

What my query does is to join both tables and print the amount of products ordered and the amount of products already registered. I would like to get as result the following table

```
Item Code| Name | Quantity_Ordered | Quantity_Registered
  00000  |  A   |         3        |         1
  11111  |  B   |         2        |         0
```

My query works whenever the item exist on "PickingItem", if it doesn't it prints the same "Quantity_Registered" as the above row, using my query I get as result the following table

```
Item Code| Name | Quantity_Ordered | Quantity_Registered
  00000  |  A   |         3        |         1
  11111  |  B   |         2        |         1(this is wrong)
```

This is the query i'm using

```
SELECT C.Barcode AS 'Item Code',C.ProductName AS 'Name', C.Quantity AS 'Quantity_Ordered', ISNULL(P.Quantity,0) AS 'Quantity_Registered'
FROM PICKING.OrderPickingItem P
JOIN PICKING.OrderPicking OP ON P.PickingID = OP.PickingID
JOIN ORDERS.ConsignmentItem C ON OP.ConsignmentID = C.ConsignmentID
WHERE P.PickingID = 1 --For testing
```

Anyone know what could I do to, if the product doesn't exist on OrderPickingItem, then set P.Quantity = 0 for that specific row?

EDIT:
Structure of the tables

OrderPickingItem

```
PickingItemID PK
PickingID FK
ConsignmentItemID FK
Quantity
--other not used columns for this query
```

OrderPicking

```
PickingID PK
ConsignmentID FK
--other not used columns for this query
```

ConsignmentItem

```
ConsignmentItemID PK
ConsignmentID FK
Barcode
Quantity
ProductName
--other not used columns for this query
```

Comment: A single quote is meant to delimit string literals not names. Standard SQL uses double quotes for names; MySQL also uses the backtick. In my opinion it is best to go without them; simply use names that need no quotes, but are valid as is.

Comment: You say you are getting the first result, but I don't see how. You'd need an outer join for this when you have no match for ID 1 in the picking tables. As to the second result, I don't see how you could get this either. Somehow your sample table data seems not to match the results you are showing.

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server. Which of the two DBMS are you actually using? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Editted the question, I'm getting the 2nd result, instead of the 1st result which is what I want, removed the tag. I'm sorry, still new on this website

Comment: There are three tables in your query, but you are showing us only two of them. In your query the table OrderPickingItem has a column PickingID. The table you are showing is called PickingItem and has no such column. Please fix this, so we get an idea of what may be wrong.

Comment: Check my edit, sorry for leaving out details

Comment: Okay, so a ConsignmentItem belongs to a Consignment. The OrderPicking also refers to a Consignment and the OrderPickingItem to a ConsignmentItem - hopefully of the same Consignment as its OrderPicking. Your data model doesn't guarantee this. (I think you would have to use composite keys to guarantee it.) Have you checked that your data is consistent? As is you may want to join ConsignmentItem on both the ConsignmentItemID and ConsignmentID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are obviously looking for an outer join:, you want to show `ConsignmentItem` records even when there is no matching picking.

```
select 
  C.Barcode AS "Item Code",
  C.ProductName AS "Name", 
  C.Quantity AS "Quantity_Ordered", 
  ISNULL(P.Quantity, 0) AS "Quantity_Registered"
from ORDERS.ConsignmentItem c
left join PICKING.OrderPicking op on OP.ConsignmentID = C.ConsignmentID
left join PICKING.OrderPickingItem P on P.PickingID = OP.PickingID
                                     and P.ConsignmentItemID = C.ConsignmentItemID;
```

Comment: It doesn't work with either LEFT OUTER or RIGHT OUTER...Any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: What I want is that if there is no PickingItem it shows the ConsignmentItem but with a 0 on "Quantity Registered" because it doesn't exists yet.

Comment: This is what this query does. When there is no PickingItem, a null is selected for P.Quantity, which is translated to 0 via ISNULL. If you get different results, then your data is different from what you think it is or there is something you haven't told us yet. What are the tables' primary keys?

Comment: I've added a condition on ConsignmentItemID to the query, so we can be sure the OrderPickingItem  matches the ConsignmentItem.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your time Thorsten :)

Answer (score 0):

Do an outer join and something like ifnull(p.id, 0) for the quantity in the select clause.